# AngularJS and Spring boot web application as a standalone desktop app

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, desktop-application, google-chrome-app

I would like to build a web application including server and database component, package it and ship it as desktop application. The application should give a native desktop app feel and work even when no internet is available. 
When internet is available, the data should be able to sync (solicited and unsolicited) to a hosted web server (Syncing at the database level).

I investigated the chrome packaged apps, which can launch the HTML5, css3 and Javascript based UI apps without the need of a browser, using webkit.  The point i am not clear of is whether the packaged apps will be able to package the server and database component as well?
Or should i be using separate packaging to install the server and database. 
I prefer it to be a single package installation.

I can think of using .Net/SwingX/Java FX/Adobe AIR to develop a desktop app, but one of the farsighted goal is to project our solution in a SaaS model so i like to stick to web app only.

I know it is not a tech specific question rather based on choosing and defining right tool and architecture. I have searched on web and did not find a concrete solution to this use case.

Comment: Have you considered client side database eg IndexedDB, rather than packaging the entire server and database. This way you could provide offline support and sync with server after going online.

Comment: Hi Rohit, One of our requirement is to do db level synchronization with the central server. Also the data is going to be moderate with few tens thousand rows. I am not sure if the IndexedDB is capable to support this.

Comment: The DB limit is matter of testing/prototyping your app. Db sync is out of question though.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your inputs, i believe IndexedDB does not support relational operations, i plan to use PostgreSQL for both my web and desktop app components and might have to look out for custom packaging and installation scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something similar to [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/tech_stack.html), it uses Angular JS and Spring Boot as main frameworks.

From their website:

Single Web page application:

- Responsive Web Design
- HTML5 Boilerplate
- Twitter Bootstrap
- AngularJS
- Full internationalization support with Angular Translate
- Optional Compass / Sass support for CSS design
- Optional WebSocket support with Spring Websocket

Comment: JHipster or any other scaffolding tool won't suffice my requirement of desktop app - web app synergy.

Answer (score 0):

Spring, Angular Js and PouchDB would help for syncing the data when internet is available.

There is a nice description in 
http://www.mircozeiss.com/building-offline-applications-with-angularjs-and-pouchdb/